# A few questions about string formating in python. Alignment

Tags: python, string, alignment

**FIRST QUESTION**

For example, if i want to print a lot of lines with the same width, i could use

```
print(f'{"INFO":=^50}')
print(f'{"some info":<50}')
print(f'{"another info":>50}')
```

And will get

```
=======================INFO=======================
some info                                         
                                      another info
```

But, what if I want to get something like this?

```
=======================INFO=======================
some info.............................another info
```

*Ok.*
I can do it

```
print(f'{"INFO":=^50}')
print('some info' + f'{"another info":.>{50-len("some info")}}')
```

Maybe python has another, the easiest way to do it?

**SECOND QUESTION**

For align we can use >, <, ^, and =
And = works only with numbers. And it works the same as >

For example

```
print(f'{13:.=5}')
print(f'{13:.>5}')
...13
...13
```

So Why do we need =, if it works the same? To be sure that the value is a number? What are the pluses it gives more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is an alignment inbetween two variables. That's quite specific. What then about alignment between three variables, four etc... ?

You can however approach it as an alignment problem for each of the two variables: split the 50 in two parts.

```
print(f'{"INFO":=^50}')
print(f'{"some info":.<25}{"another info":.>25}')

=======================INFO=======================
some info.............................another info
```

Answer (score 2):

For your second question, the answer is in [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language):

> '='
>
> Forces the padding to be placed after the sign (if any) but before the
>   digits. This is used for printing fields in the form ‘+000000120’.
>   This alignment option is only valid for numeric types. It becomes the
>   default when ‘0’ immediately precedes the field width.

This becomes clear when you have a signed number:

```
print(f'{-13:0=5}')
# -0013

print(f'{-13:0>5}')
# 00-13
```

Comment: Thank you! I should search information more carefully :)